# How to refresh android gallery after moving an image

Tags: android, gallery

In my app, I have to remove an image from gallery whenever user share the image through my app  .But I dont know how to do this. I have already tried

```
SendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

But it dint help it, rather it quits gallery with a message of `MediaScanner is running.`

If you have any other idea to do this , please share

Answer (score 0):

You might be using One ArrayList to bind the Gallery from list of images (Sdcard ) . After deleting you have to **rebind the Adapter** view. Before that Use **SendBroadcast** method.

So After rebinding Adapter list or array will get refreshed.(It will automatically get neglect if the item is not there in the sdcard while reading the no of files and the files.  ).

hope this will help you.